# Before the season began, what odds did Vegas give the Orioles of winning the AL East in 2014?

Tags: baseball, betting

Looking at various websites' pre-season predictions for the major league baseball teams, many at places like ESPN and MLB.com had the Red Sox and Rangers doing very well and the Orioles typically out of the playoffs or worse if they got very specific.  Some magazines I saw had the Orioles dead last.  CBSsports.com's Jon Heyman seems to have [come closest](http://www.cbssports.com/mlb/writer/jon-heyman/24506108/season-predictions-how-the-mlb-division-races-will-shake-out). What odds did Vegas give the O's at the beginning of the season? Also, were any bets taken that the Nationals and Orioles might play in the World Series this year?  If so, what were the odds?

Answer (score 1):

As for the odds of the Orioles winning the division, on 2-25 they were:

> ORIOLES 10-1 (15-1)

Which was 4th in the division, or second to last.

[Link to odds](http://linemakers.sportingnews.com/mlb/2014-02-25/world-series-odds-mlb-baseball-props-betting-lines-win-totals-yankees-orioles)

When it comes to the two teams playing in the worlds series, I would imagine that would be hard/impossible to find.  It would most likely be an individual bet, which I cannot find or haven't heard of.

However the odds of each team winning their pennant are published in the same document.

> 2014 NL Pennant: Nationals 5-1 (9-2)
>
> 2014 AL Pennant: Orioles 20-1 (15-1)

Comment: The odds would be more interesting after they signed Nelson Cruz.

Comment: @BruceJames They signed Nelson Cruz on **2-24-14** and these odds are from **2-25-14**, meaning after they signed him.  [Baseball Reference -- Nelson Cruz](http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/c/cruzne02.shtml#trans)